# Python : overflow while subtraction

Tags: python, integer-overflow

```
import cv2
image1 = cv2.imread('one.jpg', 0)
image2 = cv2.imread('two.jpg', 0)
diff   = image1 - image2
```

For the above code, for some values, overflow due to subtraction is taking place.
For eg:

`238 - 254 = 240`

What can I do to prevent this overflow and instead get `-16` as the answer?

Comment: signed int iso unsigned byte as type?

Comment: right now unsigned int8. shall I make it signed?

Comment: yep, that is an unsigned byte.

Comment: How can  I do that?some numpy function?

Comment: int(238) - int(254)? I wouldn't know, because I stay away from python as much as I can.

Comment: As long as the values are Python integers, there won't be any issue. If you are dealing with ctypes such as c_short or c_ushort, you will have issues.

Python will also even automatically convert the integer to a long, or automatically use a long if the value exceeds the limit.
https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesnumeric.html

In short, I doubt you are doing this in "pure Python". Maybe some code would help?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh The code uses `cv2.imread()` which returns Numpy arrays. So all necessary information is in the code above.

Comment: @BlackJack, that was added in the last 3 hours to the example, while my comment was made before that. I'm glad she added it so this clarifies things a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's the optimized answer after you have provided the cv2 module.

Your answer showed the issue:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> img = cv2.imread('myimage.jpg', 0)
>>> img.dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

This means, as you correctly stated, that it is an unsigned 8-bit integer, which can only take values from 0-255.

You can, however, automatically convert the array to a better dtype which is much more memory efficient than doing int(value).
For example...

```
>>> img[0][0] 
0
>>> img[0][0] -= 1
>>> img[0][0]
255 # since it's uint8
>>> img[0][0] += 1
>>> img2 = img.astype('uint16')
>>> img2[0][0] -= 1
>>> img2[0][0]
65535 # since it's uint16
```

You an also convert to other types other than uint8, 16, 32, and 64. For example...

```
>>> img3 = img2.astype('int64') # signed int64
>>> img3[0][0] -= 7000000
>>> img3[0][0]
-6934465
```

In short, rather than using Python's built-in type conversion, you can manually specify the dtypes from uint8-64 and int8-64 (and maybe more) using NumPy's dtypes, by specifying the newarray = array.astype('type'), creating a compact and efficient array using the new dtype. You can also specificy other types, such as 'int', 'bool', 'object', etc., showing the versatility and utility of NumPy arrays.

To read more about the dtypes and how to use them, the link to the SciPy documentation is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).

Answer (score 1):

The datatype of the above numbers was `unsigned int8`, that can take values from `0 to 255`.

`238 - 254 = -16`, and since `uint8` doesn't have representation for negative numbers, it was giving `240` as the answer.

Instead, convert the numbers to `int8 (-128 to 127)` or `int16 (-32768 to 32767)`.

Comment: Nancy please share the actual code you used to set this up including the libraries you are using. As @alexanderhuszag mentioned, it seems certain that you have abstracted your problem away from code. Future users of your library might miss the solution without the name and it probably wont work for users of other libraries. Also, if you are using numpy, converting your numbers to python ints is probably not an optimal solution.

Comment: @kobejohn I was using `cv2` library. The `cv2.imread()` function takes values as `uint8`

Comment: Thanks for updating the question! It's much clearer now.

Comment: Converting to `int8` still could result in over- or underflows as the maximum distance between two unsigned 8 bit values can be 255 (or -255).

Comment: @BlackJack Yes of course. In my problem,`int8` served the purpose.